# Arreglos php css

Tags: php

Tengo los siguientes card (tarjetas) las cuales son arrays  con informaciones adentros , abajo me trae muchos arrays mas   pero ahora quiero que cuando aprete el estado que esta en el select me traiga por el estado que seleccione Ejmplo aprete trujillo me aparescan todo los de trujillo...  he intentado con javascript con evento del clik pero ala hora de aparece solo muestra cosas como texto (el css no muestra y si incluyo css simplemente no muestra)

ESTO ES PARTE DEL CODIGO.. la parte de los card son simplente otro array

```
<?php
$stads= array("MIRANDA", "AMAZONA", "ANZOATEGUI"," APURE"," ARAGUA"," BARINAS"," CARABOBO"," COJEDES"," DELTA AMACURO"," DISTRITO CAPITAL"," CARACAS"," FALCON"," LARA"," MERIDA"," MONAGAS"," NUEVA ESPARTA"," PORTUGUESA","SUCRE","TACHIRA"," TRUJILLO"," VARGAS"," YARACUY"," ZULIA ");
$arrlength= count($stads);
echo "
<div class='col-md-3'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for='cuadro1'>Estados:</label>
            <select class='form-control' id='cuadro1'>
";

echo "<option value='' id='cuadro2'></option>";
for ($x=0; $x < $arrlength ; $x++) { 
 if ($stads [$x]!=null ) {
    $cc= $stads[$x];

echo "<option value='$cc' id='cuadro2'>$cc</option>";
    }
}
echo " </select>
    </div>
</div>";
?>

     <br>
     <br>
     <hr>
<script>
document.getElementById("cuadro1").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("cuadro3").innerHTML = "<?php echo"(ACA NO PUEDO INCLUIR CSS )"  ?>";
}
</script>

<div id="cuadro3"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veo varias cosa que estas haciendo mal en tu codigo.

El evento para registrar un cambio de select es change y no click:

```
document.getElementById("cuadro1").addEventListener("change", myFunction);
```

No entiendo lo que intentas decir con "ACA NO PUEDO INCLUIR CSS".

Puedes introducir el css directamente en el codigo html con el atributo style por ejemplo:

```
document.getElementById("cuadro3").innerHTML = "<?php echo"<span style=\"color:red;\">Hola</span>"  ?>";
```

O si lo deseas puedes escribir tu css en el archivo actual, al mostrar tu codigo html con javascript los estilos se aplicaran automáticamente:

```
<script>
...............

    document.getElementById("cuadro3").innerHTML = "<?php echo"<span class=\"estilo1\">Hola</span>"  ?>";
.................
</script>
<style>
.estilo1 {
    color:red;
}
</style>
```

Tampoco entiendo porque utilizas la sentencia PHP dentro de la variable JAVASCRIPT. Explícanos porque lo haces para poder ayudarte.

Un saludo

Comment: jeje mil gracias .. estaba colocando algunas cosas mal.. y reconocer el css de forma lineal o sea si le doy un espacio no reconoce esa parte .. por eso no me daba